# Get Index after comparing Dataframes with .eq()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a Web-Scraping application, I'm comparing some data from my database with some data, which I scraped from a Website. I save the data in two different columns of my Dataframe.

Comparing works well! I get the amount of Rows which have the same value in the 2 columns.
But as my project keeps growing, I also want to know on which index the comparison returns true. How can I do this?

***Some additional information***

My Dataframe:

```
df_single["Database"]:
Schloss Haindorf Hotelbetriebs GmbH
1. Aichfelder Druck Gesellschaft m.b.H.
Rössler Elektro Korbel
Elektro Schefbänker 
AWESOME X e.U.


df_single["Scraped"]:
Schloss Haindorf Hotelbetriebs GmbH
1. Aichfelder Druck Gesellschaft m.b.H.
Elektro Rössler OG
Elektro Schefbänker KG
AWESOME X e.U.
```

My comparison with `.eq()`

```
same_single = df_single["Database"].str.lower().eq(df_single["Scraped"].str.lower()).sum()
```

***My Output:***

```
[IN:] print(same_single)
[OUT:] 3
```

***Wanted Output:***

```
[IN:] print(index where comparison = true)
[OUT:]Comparison was true at Index: 3,5 and 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter index values by mask to `idx` and then join values with separator together:

```
mask = df_single["Database"].str.lower().eq(df_single["Scraped"].str.lower())

idx = df_single.index[mask]

print (f"Comparison was true at Index: {', '.join(idx.astype(str))}")
```

Or:

```
print ("Comparison was true at Index: {}".format(', '.join(idx.astype(str))))
```

Comment: Second time you give me a wonderful, easy to understand answer. I appreciate it.